# How to properly save Database object to database using React.js and .NET

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am trying to save `Object` to `Database` through `HTML` `Form`. My problem is thath I am still getting `null` from object.

PS: I cannot use `Entity Framework`

**React.js code:**

```
    const [Fname, setFname] = useState('');
    const [Lname, setLname] = useState('');
    const [Email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [PhoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');


 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();


        try {
            const formData = {
                fname: Fname.trim(),
                lname: Lname.trim(),
                email: Email.trim(),
                phone_number: PhoneNumber.trim()
            };
            console.log(formData.fname);
            const response = await axios.post("/api/user/registration", formData);
            console.log(response.data); 
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error); 
        }
    };


<form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4"
      >
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            htmlFor="firstName"
          >
            First Name
          </label>
          <input
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="Fname"
            name="Fname"
            type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter your first name"
                      onChange={handleFirstNameChange}
            value={Fname}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            htmlFor="lastName"
          >
            Last Name
          </label>
......
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("/api/user/registration")]
        public IActionResult Post(Users user)
        {
            try
            {
                users.Save(user);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (InvalidInput ex)
            {

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

**Save method:**

```
public void Save(Users user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("User cannot be null");
            }

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Omega_Conn")))
            {
                conn.Open();
                query = "INSERT INTO Users (fname, lname, email, phone_number) VALUES(@fname, @lname, @email, @phone_number);";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    if (user.Fname.GetType() != typeof(string) || user.Lname.GetType() != typeof(string)
                        || user.Email.GetType() != typeof(string) || user.Phone_number.GetType() != typeof(string) 
                        || user.Phone_number.Length > 9 
                        )
                    {
                        throw new InvalidInput("Inputs are not valid");
                    }
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", user.Fname );
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", user.Lname);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.Email);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_number", user.Phone_number);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
```